# Problem with generic parameters and Self keyword in Trait methods. the trait RequestBuilderTrait cannot be made into an object

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'm trying to mock some structs by making them implement traits but I encounter an error when I define a trait as return type for a method:

> the trait `RequestBuilderTrait` cannot be made into an object.

> consider moving `send_form` to another trait.
> consider moving `send_body` to another trait.
> consider moving `method` to another trait.
> consider moving `post` to another trait.
> consider moving `get` to another trait.
> consider moving `put` to another trait.
> consider moving `delete` to another trait.
> consider moving `query` to another trait.
> consider moving `headers` to another trait.
> consider moving `header` to another trait.
> consider moving `basic_auth` to another trait.
> consider moving `bearer_auth` to another trait.

> for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be >resolvable dynamically.

After some research I found that traits use a vtable where all of their methods signature are stated so those methods need to be sized to make trait objects safe. So I think the problem is that some of my methods have generic parameters and use Self keyword as return type. I thought that if I was using a Box type and simple reference it would solve the problem but this is not the case, I have the feeling there is no solution for this situation. Do you think there is any solution ? I know that I could use `where Self: Sized` for methods which return Self but it makes that method unusable later.

The error appears on the method which have `Box<dyn RequestBuilderTrait>` as return type

My code :

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait HttpClientTrait: Send + Sync {
    fn builder(&self) -> Box<dyn RequestBuilderTrait>;
    fn get_client(&self) -> &Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>>;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct HttpClient {
    http_client: Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>>,
}
impl HttpClient {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        HttpClient {
            http_client: Client::builder().build::<_, Body>(HttpsConnector::with_native_roots()),
        }
    }
}

impl HttpClientTrait for HttpClient{
    fn builder(&self) -> Box<dyn RequestBuilderTrait> {
        RequestBuilder::new(&self.http_client)
    }

    fn get_client(&self) -> &Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>> {
        &self.http_client
    }
}

#[async_trait]
pub trait RequestBuilderTrait {
    async fn send_and_get_hyper_response_future(mut self) -> Result<ResponseFuture, RequestError>;
    async fn send(mut self) -> Result<RequestResponse, RequestError>;
    async fn send_form<T: Serialize + Send + Sync>(mut self, form: &T) -> Result<RequestResponse, RequestError> ;
    async fn send_body<T: Serialize + Send + Sync>(mut self, object: &T) -> Result<RequestResponse, RequestError>;
    async fn send_multipart(mut self, multipart: MultipartForm) -> Result<RequestResponse, RequestError>;
    fn method( self, url: &str, method: Method) -> Box<Self>;
    fn post( self, url: &str) -> Box<Self>;
    fn get( self, url: &str) -> Box<Self>;
    fn put( self, url: &str) -> Box<Self>;
    fn delete( self, url: &str) -> Box<Self>;
    fn query<P: Serialize>( self, parameters: &P) -> Result<Box<Self>, ResponseError>;
    fn headers<K: Clone + IntoHeaderName>( self, headers: &[(K, &str)]) -> Result<Box<Self>, ResponseError>;
    fn header<K: IntoHeaderName>(self, key: K, val: &str) -> Result<Box<Self>, ResponseError>;
    fn basic_auth( self, username: &str, password: &str) -> Result<Box<Self>, ResponseError>;
    fn bearer_auth( self, token: &str) -> Result<Box<Self>, ResponseError>;
}

pub struct RequestBuilder<'a> {
    client: &'a Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>, Body>,
    builder: Option<Builder>,
    request: Option<Request<Body>>,
}

#[async_trait]
impl<'a> RequestBuilderTrait for RequestBuilder<'a>{
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, trait objects cannot contain generic functions, as described in the error message. Is there a reason you need trait objects instead of just normal generics? This feels like an XY problem

Comment: Yes I need trait objects to mock HttpClient  and RequestBuilder structs and then be able to unit test more easily methods which use those two structs

Comment: What part of that requires trait objects (i.e. `Box<dyn Trait>`) instead of plain generics? For example, if you have a function that does some HTTP requests, why can't it look something like: `fn load_data<T: HttpClientTrait>(client: T)` rather than `fn load_data(client: Box<dyn HttpClientTrait>)`? Both of those allow you to use a mocked http client in tests

Comment: You need _traits_ for mocking, but you don't necessarily need trait _objects._ Can't you make the methods you want to test generic?

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys. I tried what you suggested and it could have worked if I didnt had the method  `fn builder(&self) -> Box<dyn RequestBuilderTrait>` in the `HttpClientTrait ` because if I use `T` as return type instead I can't initialize  and return structs which implement the `RequestBuilderTrait`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: IIUC, you can use an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html?highlight=associated%20type#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types): `pub trait HttpClientTrait: Send + Sync { type RequestBuilder: RequestBuilderTrait; fn builder(&self) -> Self::RequestBuilder; }` allowing you to mock the `RequestBuilder` alongside the `HttpClient`.

Comment: Didnt know about this feature, thank you.